# vsinstr.exe can't read .dll files being built from respective Visual Studio builds

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I am using a PowerShell script to get the code coverage for the DLLs in my project.

It keeps erroring out on every DLL.

I have narrowed it down to VSInstr.exe.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools>vsinstr.exe -coverage C:\GitRepos\ProjectName\src\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.dll
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 14.0.25420 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Error VSP1033: The file 'C:\GitRepos\ProjectName\src\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.dll' does not contain a recognized executable image.
```

If I clean and rebuild in 2017 and try the same exe in the 2017 Performance Tools folder I get the same exact Error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Performance Tools>vsinstr.exe -coverage C:\GitRepos\ProjectName\src\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.dll
Microsoft (R) VSInstr Post-Link Instrumentation 15.0.26720 x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Error VSP1033: The file 'C:\GitRepos\ProjectName\src\ProjectName\bin\ProjectName.dll' does not contain a recognized executable image.
```

Are these .dll files for the project not being built correctly in the respective IDEs?  Are there some options or preferences in VS that I need to set for VSInstr to be able to read the DLLs correctly?

I am not the only one here in the office that gets this error when running VSInstr.exe against the .dll files created from Visual Studio.

I know that they can be read as a coworker in another office is able to pull down my branch from git, build it and successfully run the .dll files through the PowerShell script and through the VSInstr.exe command line, but I can't go to him everytime I need this script run for this and other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Found that we were building with Any CPU on a 64bit pc but there is a x64 version of vsinstr.exe inside of

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64
```

that should have been referenced instead for these .dll files being created during the build.